# ASP.NET MVC Area not picking up the correct route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am in the process of debugging a routing issue on my MVC 3 application and I am using Phil Hacks routing debugger.

I cannot seem to work out where the route highlighted in yellow below is originating.  Each time I run my application with the following request

http://www.mywebsite.com/auth/login?ReturnUrl=/

this route comes first and then gives me a 404 error as I do not have an index action. As you can see I have set my default routes to use the Login action method but still this route persists.

[image]

I have the following route configurations:

AuthAreaRegistration

```
public class AuthAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
{
    public override string AreaName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Auth";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "login",
            "auth/login/{*returnPath}",
            new { controller = "Auth", action = "LogIn", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        context.MapRoute(
            "Auth_default",
            "Auth/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Auth", action = "LogIn", id = "" }
        );
    }
}
```

Global.asax (Using T4 MVC Templates)

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Home",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            MVC.Home.Index(), new { id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new string[] { "MyNamespace.WebUI.Controllers" }

        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            MVC.Home.Index(), new { id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new string[] { "MyNamespace.WebUI.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t like to answer my own question but after a day of trying to solve this problem I thought I would post the answer in case anyone else has the same issue.

It turns out that my application was holding onto old routes and populating them into my route collection. I deleted all the files in my bin folder and rebuilt my solution and everything worked as it should.

I have answered this question in a little more detail here:

[Does ASP.NET MVC create default routes for areas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861702/does-asp-net-mvc-create-default-routes-for-areas)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the fact that you have an **area** called **Auth** and a **controller** called **Auth** outside of the areas.

MVC will try to match your url against Auth area first but you actually want it to hit your auth controller outside an area.

The best way to solve it imho is to avoid a ambiguous names of controllers/areas.

Comment: Thanks for the response but my auth controller is actually in my auth area ie Areas/Auth/Controllers/AuthController. This to me is the logical place for the controller. Although I do get where you are coming from with the whole ambiguous naming of controllers/areas.

Comment: If you want to call an action Login on controller Auth in area Auth than your url should be www.mywebsite.com/Auth/Auth/Login

Comment: Thanks Jakub but I am trying to get it so its easy to read in code and url friendly ie www.mywebsite.com/auth/login. I am doing this by catching the auth/login request pattern and assigning it to controller = Auth, action = LogIn which is the first route in my AuthAreaRegistration. This does catch and process it sometimes however I do not know where this other route I mentioned above is coming from and why it appears at the top of the routing list.

Comment: If you want just /auth/login and presumably /auth/logout than why don't you move the controller out of the area? It seems to me you've put the controller inside an area and then you're trying to pretend it's not there... (the top route is Auth_default)